# Properly update Django model's foreign key property

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-orm

I have a Django Model named `EmailSendingTask`. This is the whole model-

```
class EmailSendingTask(models.Model):
    order = models.OneToOneField(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order')
    status = EnumChoiceField(SetupStatus, default=SetupStatus.active)
    time_interval = EnumChoiceField(TimeInterval, default=TimeInterval.five_mins)
    immediate_email = models.OneToOneField(PeriodicTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='immediate_email')
    scheduled_email = models.OneToOneField(PeriodicTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='scheduled_email')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'EmailSendingTask'
        verbose_name_plural = 'EmailSendingTasks'
            
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'EmailSendingTask: Order = {self.order}'
```

The `immediate_email` and `scheduled_email` fields are responsible for holding two PeriodicTask objects.

I have created a function called `disable_scheduled_email`, which is responsible for disabling the `scheduled_email`'s periodic task. The detail of the function is here-

```
    def disable_scheduled_email(self):
        print(f'Disabling scheduled email...')
        self.scheduled_email.enabled = False
        self.save(update_fields=['scheduled_email'])
```

Now, whenever I call this function and print the value of the `self.scheduled_email.enabled`, I find it `False`. But, when I try to look at the Django Admin site, the periodic task's `enabled` value remains as `True`. Why is it happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments into the **Django Shell** I have found out that, I was not specifically calling `save()` to the foreign key (`scheduled_email`). I have just added `self.scheduled_email.save()` into the `disable_scheduled_email` function. So, the whole function became like:

```
    def disable_scheduled_email(self):
        print(f'Disabling scheduled email...')
        self.scheduled_email.enabled = False
        # self.save(update_fields=['scheduled_email'])
        self.scheduled_email.save() #instead of self.save(...), wrote this
```